# Way to show code snippet in android app?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I want to **show some code snippet in my android application**. All i know is that I can use webview.

- Is there is some other (better) way to do it ?
- I want to show them fetched from DB and formatted in code style.

  As per Android developer forum, regarding `WebView`:

> If your goal is only to display some HTML as a part of your UI, this
>   is probably fine; the user won't need to interact with the web page
>   beyond reading it, and the web page won't need to interact with the
>   user.

But I need users to say like / dislike / comment on the code snippet. How can that be achieved then ?
As of now, I can only think of using `WebView + Android TextView / EditView`

**Is there is better (or efficient) way ?**

Comment: have you found the solution yet? As its been 5 years since you asked the question